# UI Grid showing only last record many times on infinite scroll

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, infinite-scroll, ui-grid

[Before Scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDA9k.png)

[After Scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqOf0.png)

In Grid on first time load I am getting data properly.
After scrolling down it is getting problem.
It displays last record from the first load's last record in every row.

Below is my code for infinite scroll function.

```
$scope.getDataDown = function() {
  var promise = $q.defer();
  $scope.lastPage++;
  if ($scope.data.length < $scope.total) {
    $http(getRequest()).success(function(data) {
      promise.resolve();
      var jb = JSON.stringify(data.content);
      $scope.gridApi.infiniteScroll.saveScrollPercentage();
      $scope.data = $scope.data.concat(data.content);
      $scope.total = data.total ? data.total : data.length;
      $scope.length = $scope.data.length;
      $scope.gridApi.infiniteScroll.dataLoaded(false,
          $scope.lastPage < ($scope.total / $scope.pageSize));
    }).error(function(error) {
          $scope.gridApi.infiniteScroll.dataLoaded();
        });
  }
  return promise.promise;
};
```

Comment: one more thing I am getting proper data in "data.content" but while displaying it is getting problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Funciton is right but I used below function in my code it was conflicting with this function

`$scope.gridOptions.rowIdentity = function(row) {
    return row.id;
};`